# Run a function after async function

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular-httpclient

I'm working on Angular with HttpClient and encounter the following problem:

I have the following function that save the amount from the database locally

```
getAmount(){
this.httpClient.get('https://myfirebasedatabase.com/test.json').subscribe(
  (response)=>{
    this.amount = response['total'];
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log('error' + error);
  }
);
}
```

this function is working good but when I try to use the variable `this.amount` it's undefined

```
this.getAmount();
console.log(this.amount);     //output undefined
```

I've try to do `this.getAmount().then ...` but cannot because it's of type void.
I've also try to create a promise for getAmount but cannot use then() on type subscription.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give me a look wider to your code. when do you log `this.amount`?

Comment: note that http requests are async. it means it takes some times to get response. so if you log your variable just after request, you almost get undefined variable.

Comment: @jabbar I have a function   setAmount(amountToAdd:number){this.getAmount();console.log(this.amount); ...}

Comment: Yeah I know that is async . If i do my console.log after 2s it's working but would like to do something clean instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with asynchronous services like `getAmount()`, the Angular way is to return a Observable which resolves with the value you want to access in subscriber. The usual approach is instead of subscribing to the service call, return it possibly after some extra RxJs piping:

```js
getAmount(){
return this.httpClient.get('https://myfirebasedatabase.com/test.json')
    .pipe(
        pluck('total')   // same as map(response => response.total)
     );
}
```

Then in consuming code, use `subscribe` instead of `then`:

```js
this.getAmount().subscribe(total => { 
    this.amount = total;
    console.log(this.amount);
});
```

Comment: Big "+" for using pluck operator - never heard of it. But on the second thouth maybe map is more verbose for a reason. But cleaver, I cannot deny that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap the client call into an async function so you can just await for its response in the main body of your method? for example.

```
const getAmountAsync = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.httpClient.get('https://myfirebasedatabase.com/test.json').subscribe(
        (response)=>{
            resolve(response['total'])
        },
        (error) => {
            reject(error)
        }
        );
})
}

//main body:

this.amount = await getAmountAsync()
```